# Angular Repository Pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement the Repository pattern in Angular, here is where I am at:

So, at the moment from my controller I will call my repository with

```
RepositoryDataService.get(supplier_url, 1);
```

So I am always passing in supplier_url with each get, update etc

what I would like to do is new up a repository with the type name.  ie.

```
var supplierRepo = new RepositoryDataService('suppliers');
var userRepo = new RepositoryDataService('users');

supplierRepo.get("babs").then(function(data){ supplier= data});
userRepo.get("peter").then(function(data){ user = data});

supplierRepo.update(id);
users.update(id);
```

This is my data service

```
(function () {
"use strict";

RepositoryDataService.$inject = ['$http'];

angular.module('webclient.common.data').factory('RepositoryDataService', RepositoryDataService);

function RepositoryDataService($http) {
    var url = 'http://application/';

    var service = {
        get: get
    };

    return service;

    function get(controllerName,id) {
        var urlApi = url + controllerName + '/';

        if (typeof (id) !== "undefined" && id !== null)
            return $http.get(urlApi + id)
                        .then(function (response) { return response.data; });
        else
            return $http.get(urlApi)
                        .then(function (response) { return response.data; });
    };

    };
}());
```

I don't want to use $resource, I would like to use $http

Thanks

Comment: whether you use $resource or not this won't work : var users = userRepo.get("peter"); you have  to do userRepo.get("peter").then(function(data){ users = data}); For the rest you would have to change you should convert your service into a factory of service.

Comment: Why not use `$resource`? REST is a natural pattern for repositories.

Comment: Here's a good read on when to use factory vs service vs provider http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/  Should steer you in the right direction

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help here but I am trying to achieve in Angular what I have done in the past with c# as in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/getting-started-with-repository-pattern-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: IMO that's an anti-pattern in c# and probably one here as well.  In angular, it's going to interfere with testability and clarity of code to do it this way.